# Why doesn't nuetron-neutron bound state exist?

Tags: particle-physics, solid-state-physics

For parallel spins, our instructor told us that it is because of pauli exclusion principle. Here is my doubt : if total spin is 1. That means spin part of wavefunction is symmetric, but if the spatial part of the wave function is anti-symmetric , the overall state will be anti-symmetric, which is good. How does then pauli exclusion principle rule out this possibility? Please, clarify.

Comment: A neutron-neutron is comprised of inner quarks which are not stable in such a configuration.

Comment: So, the spatial part of the wavefunction can only be symmetric? (In that case, it  is clear that the state wont exist)

Comment: @FarmanUllah: You're oversimplifying the question. The exclusion principle rules out the existence of some states but not others. Your question is a duplicate, so please take some time to study the answers to that one.

Comment: Space symmetric s-states are normally the lowest energy ones.

Comment: @CosmasZachos: I think you're misapplying something that doesn't apply here. Presumably you mean something like the bonds in an H2 molecule? This has to do with specifics of the strong force.

Comment: @Ben Crowel. To be sure. It sort of holds in quark spectroscopy. It would be nice to know how often this is violated in nuclear physics.